# segmentation fault with class pointer array of class pointer array of another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, segmentation-fault

I'm not getting any compilation errors nor am I getting any errors when try to do this with only one class pointer array of another class. When I do it with three classes. I crash.

```
#define size 10

// single point with x and y
class singlePoint{
public: 
    float xCoordinate;
    float yCoordinate;  
};

// row of points
class pointRow{
public: 
    singlePoint *pointRowArray[size];
    void makePointRowArray(int);    
    void setPointRowArray(int); 
};

// “row” of row of points
class totalSquare{
public: 
    pointRow *totalSquareArray[size];
    void makeTotalSquare(int);
    void setTotalSquare(int); 
};
//-----------------
void pointRow::makePointRowArray(int rowSize){
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
        pointRowArray[i] = new singlePoint;
    }
}

void pointRow::setPointRowArray(int rowSize){
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
        pointRowArray[i]->xCoordinate = 11;
        pointRowArray[i]->yCoordinate = 12;
    }
}

void totalSquare::makeTotalSquare(int collumnSize){
    for (int i = 0; i < collumnSize; i++){
        totalSquareArray[i] = new pointRow;
    }   
}

void totalSquare::setTotalSquare(int collumnSize){
    for (int collumnSet = 0; collumnSet < collumnSize; collumnSet++){   
        for (int rowSet = 0; rowSet < collumnSize; rowSet++){
            // my problem lies somewhere in here
            totalSquareArray[collumnSet]->pointRowArray[rowSet]->xCoordinate = 13;
            totalSquareArray[collumnSet]->pointRowArray[rowSet]->yCoordinate = 14;
        }
    }   
}


int main(void){
    // this was just a test for pointRow and it’s fine
    pointRow firstRow;
    firstRow.makePointRowArray(size);
    firstRow.setPointRowArray(size);    

    // this works up until…
    totalSquare firstSquare;
    firstSquare.makeTotalSquare(size);
    // this point. I cannot assign 25
    // I either get a bus error 10 or segmentation fault. what am I doing wrong?
    firstSquare.totalSquareArray[0]->pointRowArray[0]->xCoordinate = 25;


    return 0;
}
```

I just don't know why it works for pointRow but now totalSquare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `makePointRowArray` anywhere in your `totalSquare` case. Without that, the pointers in `pointRowArray` are uninitialised and are likely to crash your program. You can probably fix this by adding it to the following function:

```
void totalSquare::makeTotalSquare(int collumnSize){
    for (int i = 0; i < collumnSize; i++){
        totalSquareArray[i] = new pointRow;
        totalSquareArray[i]->makePointRowArray(size);
    }   
}
```

You should consider doing this in a *constructor* so that you don't forget to initialise your data when using your objects.

Comment: Will make and use a constructor. Thanks so much.